# Placing data that is generated on bottom of page to top

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page with a few foreach loops in the middle of the page. In these foreach i do a sum of some vars to at the end of the foreachloop this $var has data.

Now i want to show this data on the top of my page before the foreach wich means if I dump the var it is false or not set...

Now i would like to know what the best way is to approach such a issue?

I could do the same foreach twice also at the top to get the data but what is best practice for these kinds of problems ?

just to give a example

```
$sum = false;
echo "<center>Sum: {$sum}</center>";

$sum = 0
foreach ($a as $b) {
$sum += $b
}
```

I understand that the var is false because the loop did not happen, but for design, i want to show this at first.. so how do i do this, javascrip?

Comment: Generally people parse/manipulate the data that is going to be displayed on a page, before actually sending anything for output. So do your calculations, store them in variables then use them in your display once it's all done.

Comment: So i have to use some template engine to do so ?

Comment: No, you just do all your variable manipulation and calculations before you start working on your display. Then you use them to output your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One popular method is to manipulate your variables before you begin to process the actual output. To use your example, yes you would likely run the foreach once when processing the data, then again later on to display it.

For your specific example it may not be an obvious the benefit, but once you start working on larger pages that include more data it becomes a lot simpler to split the logic and display.

Process the data

```
<?php

$sum = 0;
foreach ($a as $b) {
  $sum += $b;
}

?>
```

Display it

```
<center>Total record(s): <?=$sum?></center>

<?php foreach($a as $b) { ?>

<p>Value: <?=$b?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Note: the shorthand syntax of `<?=$var?>` means `<?php echo $var; ?>`, and is only on by default from `PHP 5.4` onwards.

**Edit to show an alternative**

If you really only want to loop once, and are happy mixing your logic and display, you can build the HTML output that would ordinarily be inside your loop, as you calculate the sum.

```
<?php

$valuesHtml = "";
$sum = 0;
foreach ($a as $b) {
  $sum += $b;
  $valuesHtml .= "<p>Value: {$b}</p>";
}

?>

<center>Total record(s): <?=$sum?></center>

<?=$valuesHtml?>
```

Comment: so i have to do the foreach 2 times? 1 for the data and 1 for the look..?

Comment: If you really don't want to run the loop for whatever reason you can build the HTML the first time you run it, I will modify my answer with an example.

Comment: Short answer: Depends on an individuals opinion. The advantage to the first is if (when?) you transition to a framework, particularly an MVC style one, you're already splitting your logic and your view which makes implementation/migration easier. It is also in my opinion easier to maintain code that separates the two.

Comment: Hey,, im gonna update my question with some code of mine... i tried your method,, but now the data is wrong.. like it only gets 1 record or something. Could you check? maybe im making a simple mistake... i have alredy tried to rename the vars in the second loop... (left some 2;s in there... ) but did not work

Comment: Each time you iterate through your first `foreach` loop you are overwriting the values you're calculating. If, in that loop, you save them all to an array, you can then loop through that array in your display and output the values there.

Comment: Yeah,,, i was thinking about that... to place all data in a array... and then loop over that array.... it just seems "not good" when i do that.. dont know if what im doing is "right" but anyway thanks!

Comment: That way you're still starting to separate your logic and display, and also only running all of the functions the minimum number of times.